# Convolution of two independent geometric random variables with parameters $p$ and $q$

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I am trying to use Mathematica to do some computations in Advanced Probability. I am quite new to Mathematica, so I need help in understanding the Convolve function. I used Mathematica 11 to compute the convolution of two independent geometric random variables with parameters p and q respectively, I don't seem to get a closed form expression for the convolution. Here is what I have attempted:

```
Convolve[PDF[GeometricDistribution[p], k], 
 PDF[GeometricDistribution[q], k], k - n, n]
```

The output is:

```
 Convolve[\[Piecewise]  (1-p)^k p   k>=0
0   True

,\[Piecewise]   (1-q)^k q   k>=0
0   True

,k-n,n].
```

I further tried to get the same result using the Transformed distribution as follows:

```
f[x_] = PDF[GeometricDistribution[p], k];
g[y_] = PDF[GeometricDistribution[q], k];
PDF[
 TransformedDistribution[
  x + y,
  {
   x \[Distributed] ProbabilityDistribution[f[x], {x, 0, k}], 
   y \[Distributed] ProbabilityDistribution[g[x], {y, 0, k}]
   }
  ], x
 ]
```

I got the output as :

```
\[Piecewise]    k (1-p)^k p (1-q)^k q   k>0&&2 k-x==0
(1-p)^k p (1-q)^k q (2 k-x) k>0&&k-x<0&&2 k-x>0
(1-p)^k p (1-q)^k q x   k>0&&x>0&&k-x>=0
0   True
```

I am new to Mathematica so could anyone help me understand what is happening with the two codes above?

Comment: The syntax is: `Convolve[PDF[GeometricDistribution[p], k], 
 PDF[GeometricDistribution[q], k], k, n]`

Comment: @DanielHuber: This produces `Piecewise[{{(p*((1 - p)^n - (1 - q)^n)*q)/
    (Log[1 - p] - Log[1 - q]), n > 0}}, 0]` . Summarizing it by `n` from `0` to `Infinity`. one obtains `(-p + q)/(Log[1 - p] - Log[1 - q])` instead of `1`. Also in the case `p==q` `Convolve` produces `Piecewise[{{n*(1 - p)^n*p^2, n > 0}}, 0]` instead of `Piecewise[{{(1 + n)*(1 - p)^n*p^2, n >= 0}}, 0]` (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_convolutions_of_probability_distributions)). If I am not mistaken,  it looks like a bug in `Convolve`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GeometricDistribution` is a discrete distribution. Because of it, `DiscreteConvolve` should be applied:

```
DiscreteConvolve[PDF[GeometricDistribution[p], k],PDF[GeometricDistribution[q], k], k, n]
```

> `Piecewise[{{(p*q*(-(1 - p)^n + (1 - p)^n*p + (1 - q)^n -  (1 - q)^n*q))/(p - q), n >= 0}}, 0]`

To verify it

```
Sum[(p*q*(-(1 - p)^n + (1 - p)^n*p + (1 - q)^n - (1 - q)^n*q))/(p - 
q), {n, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {p, q} > 0 && {p, q} < 1]
```

> `1`

See the documentation for more info.

Comment: +1 Use `FullSimplify` to get a simpler form. For completeness you should also look at `Limit[conv, p -> q]`

Comment: @user64494: Thanks. DiscreteConvolve  worked! I verified the sum too.  Thanks a lot for all the answers received. Could you please recommend a book to learn programming in Mathematica, especially for concepts in advanced probability?

Comment: @Rosy: Thank you for good words. See the results of Google search "Probability with Mathematica" (The link is too long to be quoted here.).